# Sending data to google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm trying to enter the value of my `username` variable in a cell in a google sheet. At the moment the following is sending to sheet, so the connection is correct.

```py
userscore.update_cell(3,1,"Bob" )    # this works
```

But when I try the following code:

```py
username = input("Please enter username: ")
userscore.update_cell(3,1, + username)
# OR
userscore.update_cell(username)
```

It does not update the google sheet.

It is not important to me which cell the data is written in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you adding a `plus` before `username`? The `update_cell` function takes three arguments `(row, col, value)` so you'd need to do the following:

```
username = input("Please enter username: ")
userscore.update_cell(3, 1, username)
```

This should work.